# Lattice definition and example

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, order-theory, lattice-orders

Guys I am struggling to understand the lattice concept:

Could you help me with this silly example?

Take the collection $\{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}\}$ ordered by inclusion. This is a poset, but not a lattice since $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ have no common upper bound.

Why this is not a lattice?

This is the definition of lattice:
[image]

So  if I take $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ I have to show that the join and the meet belongs to X, right?

join $= \{0\} \vee \{1\} = {1}$ wich belongs to X. And meet$=\{0\} \wedge \{1\} = {0}$ wich belongs to X

What am I missing?

Many thanks!

Comment: $\{0\}\cup\{1\}=\{0,1\}\notin\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{1\}\}$

Comment: No, the join of $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ would be $\{0,1\}$ or some other set containing this one, but you don't have it

Comment: could you explain what your notation $\{0\}\wedge\{1\}$ and $\{0\}\vee\{1\}$ is supposed to mean?

Comment: @PinkPanther The set is ordered by inclusion. Then $\wedge=\cap$ and $\vee=\cup$.

Comment: Thanks @amrsa (again!) and @drhab!

Comment: I think there is a confusion in your question, which is, what is $X$? Is it $\{0,1\}$ or $\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{1\}\}$, and that's why you conclude that, for example, $\{0\}\wedge\{1\}=\{0\}$. Beware of this. I would say that you have a set $X=\{0,1\}$ and a family $F=\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{1\}\}$ of subsets, ordered by inclusion. Now, does $0 \in F$? does $1\in F$?

Comment: @amrsa $X = \{\emptyset, \{0 \}, \{1 \} \}$. My idea to was understand why the Power Set of $Y$ is a lattice but the $Power set - Y$ is not.

Comment: OK, but then $0 \notin X$ and $1 \notin X$, so your calculation is wrong. $\{0\}\wedge\{1\}$ has to be $\varnothing$, since the order is inclusion, and this is the only set which is contained both is $\{0\}$ and in $\{1\}$; but $\{0\}\vee\{1\}$ is not defined since $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ don't even have a common upper bound in $X$.

Comment: Remark: it is a bit tricky to work with symbols like $0$ and $1$ here. This because in set theory symbol $0$ also is used as a notation for $\varnothing$ and $1$ as a notation for $\{0\}=\{\varnothing\}$.

Comment: @amrsa  hum, I think my mistake I understand. I will come back and read more this concept of lattice, joint and meet.